# iOS Swift 3: Changing bounds of ImageView to match Aspect Fit Photo

Tags: ios, swift3, imageview

I have an imageView that takes up the vast majority of the screen because i want to ensure i use the entire width of the device without losing any resolution (using aspect fit). Simply put, I have another element that i'd like to place 5 pixels under the image; see the photos below:

[image] [image]

Please note the unwanted black space between the photo and the "RippleLikes" icon.

**So my question is as follows:** How does one change the height constraint of the imageView to match the height of the photo it contains?

Answer (score 0):

> How does one change the height constraint of the imageView to match the height of the photo it contains

The simple way is to center the image view horizontally (and vertically?) in its superview, and give it *no* height or width constraints. The image view will automatically take on the size of the image, which means its height will be the height of the photo — which is just what you said you wanted. The width part will extend off the sides of the screen, but that doesn't matter.

That, however, is not what *I* would do. I would create, in code, a new image (based on the original) that is the actual desired size, given the dimensions of this device's screen. In other words, rather than doing this with the constraints of the image *view*, I would manipulate the *image*.

Comment: Would you mind adding some swift code that would manipulate the image as per your suggestion? After attempting the simple suggestion; xcode screamed at me for not having a height constraint

Comment: Just redraw the image into an image graphics context of the desired size. — However, I assure you that an image view with neither width nor height constraint is legal. It sounds like you still have a width constraint, or else some other setting is faulty.